# how to prepend a list of items before the original list of records before returning from a controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

how to prepend a list of records before returning

Let's say i have index method is defined below. The index view expects @songs to list all the songs.

```
@top = TopChart.all

@songs = Song.order(created_at: :desc).page(params[:page]).per(20)
```

Now i want to prepend @top records in front of the @songs. for example @songs = @top + @songs. After updating the list this way paging should also work. I appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: `[].prepend` is an alias for `[].unshift`. But what's wrong with `@top + @songs`? And how will your view tell the difference between TopCharts and Songs, if they are in the same array? Post more details.

Comment: the index view is paged. In the first few entries top chart songs should be shown and all the rest will follow. that is the goal i am trying to achieve.

Comment: `@top + @songs` should combine both arrays. What is your problem with that? Does it return an unexpected result? Is there an error? What does the error message say, how does the stack trace look like? Where exactly is the error raised?

Comment: ok thanks. i have separated them out. i think it is not a good idea to mix two different categories like that. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For paging to work even after you prepend few extra records, you must give necessary offset while fetching `@songs`. You will also need to handle first page of your query separately where records from `@top` are shown.
Here is a sample code:

```
page_size = 20
if params[:page] == 1
    @top = TopChart.all
    page_offset = 0
    per_page = page_size - @top.size
else
    @top = []
    page_offset = page_size - TopChart.all.count
    per_page = page_size
end

@songs = Song.offset(page_offset).order(created_at: :desc).page(params[:page]).per(per_page)
@songs = @top + @songs
```

In this code if we are returning first page then offset is 0 but the required size of `@songs` become 20 minus the size of `@top`. However, after first page the required size of `@songs` become 20 with an offset of number of songs fetched in first page.

Note that there is an assumption: *size of `@top` is less than the page size (20 in this example)*

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `TopChart.all`? Maybe `TopChart.all.count` could be just `TopChart.count`?

Comment: Both of them generates same SQL query

Comment: Don't know why the redundance.

Comment: Can you please clarify in which two lines there is redundancy in the code?